# How to synchronize the project between a computer and a laptop with GIT?

Tags: git

I want to work with the same project on my PC and sometimes on my laptop.
How can I do that with Git instead of uploading this project to something like Dropbox etc.
I don't want to public it on the Github site because these projects are simple, easy and just for learn new things not a big project which I can boast of.
Is this possible to "copy" that from the computer to another computer (in this case laptop) in the same network?

Comment: I think you refer to this resolution: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/4948190>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git repository sync between computers, when moving around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948190/git-repository-sync-between-computers-when-moving-around)