# Eclipse CDT: From Windows to Linux

Tags: c++, cross-platform, eclipse-cdt

I have eclipse installed on windows and use cygwin to develop programs for linux. I compile using the cygwin toolchain and I also do my tests on cygwin.

Now I would like to compile my program also with the native linux toolchain and I also would like to debug it from the windows machine.

Is something possible with Indigo SR2? What is the best way to accomplish this?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh) but then I would have two projects one for windows and one for linux. I would like to have just one project for both platforms to avoid syncrhonizing the sources back and forth.

Thanks.

Comment: The tools in Linux are just the same as in Cygwin (more or less), and Eclipse CDT should use those standard tool on Linux.

Comment: I don't have eclipse installed on the linux side. How would it be possible to transfer the sources from windows to linux and execute a make via ssh?

Comment: you may share a single source pool between 2 projects, in this case  there are no need to synchronize sources. Just use filesystem links or eclipse virtual folders. Windows+Linux+VirtualBox on your host machine seem to solve your problem without Windows/Linux cross-compilation

Comment: If it's enough to just type `make` in a Cygwin terminal, you should just be able copy the files (with e.g. `scp`) build it the same on the Linux host. If you use special libraries, then they might have to be installed on the Linux host as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a cross platform development environment.

There are various tools for the job, but my choice would be [CMake](http://cmake.org). Basically, you will write CMakelists.txt file instead of Eclipse .classpath and .project files, and generate those files with cmake executable. But in details, you will need to [overcome some difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake) which are inherent in cross platform development.

I have successfully created more than one project with these tools, and they currently under a heavy load.