# Solution for using Sublime Text to edit files on a local server I created with vagrant?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sublimetext2, remote-access, vagrant

I have a headless Ubuntu server created with vagrant and normally use `vagrant ssh` to access and then mess around with the files.

I need to edit the files, and I'm not terribly keen on learning vim/emacs, so I'm wondering if I can use my editor of choice (Sublime Text 2) to edit the remote files.

How would you recommend I go about this? I've heard many solutions, FTP, rsync, vim/emacs, etc. but I'm not sure for my particular situation (Sublime and vagrant) what I would be best off doing.

Comment: I wonder how you have oversighted that from the readme. Map the folder, work on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Sublime SFTP`](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) might be a good solution for you. After the free trial is does cost US$16, but it's definitely worth it if you routinely work with files across FTP/SFTP/FTPS. It is authored by the same guy who created [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). You should be able to configure vagrant to allow this.

Another option is to use [`sshfs` with Vagrant](http://wenbinwu.com/) to create a locally-mounted filesystem that you can access directly through ST2. If you're running on OSX, I highly recommend trying out [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/). In my experience it's much easier to use than MacFUSE, is faster, a lot easier to set up, and is much more stable. Again, with the right config options vagrant should allow this pretty easily.

Comment: `sshfs` worked well for me. I wanted to expose a folder within the remote to my host, such that I could easily use x and sublime on the host to make changes on the remote.

Answer (score 17):

By default Vagrant will set up a share with your host machine automatically... `/vagrant` on the server will be mapped to the folder containing your `Vagrantfile` this allows you to edit anything in this folder and the changes will be made instantly on the ubuntu server as well.

You can also set up other shared/synced folders... [check out the documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html).

The other options you have are creating a samba share (or AFP on OSX) or something similar and then mounting the share in your host machine and using sublime as per usual.

Comment: This is correct. Although if for some reason this does not meet your needs, you can try the various alternatives for running Sublime Text over SSH here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15958056/456584

Comment: In addition, this can be augmented by setting up  shared folders in Dropbox, Google drive or similar.  This allows for nice always available development environments.