# Use Sublime over SSH: The Sequel

Tags: ssh, sublimetext2

So at my last job I tried to use Sublime over SSH, and nice people helped me solve the problem:

[How to use Sublime over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958056/how-to-use-sublime-over-ssh)

Now I'm at a new job, and I think the best way for me to go is the rmate/rsub combo, but I'm getting `Unable to connect to TextMate on localhost:52698` and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OSX, and have the capacity to do so, I highly recommend installing [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/). It's the simplest, most straightforward, and best of all least-buggy way of dealing with SSH I've found on OSX (10.8.5 for me currently, also worked for me on Lion). `osxfuse` and `sshfs` are nice, but in my experience they weren't that feature-ful, and tended to crash my machine after a while. Transmit will set you back US$34, but it is so worth it, and since it's for work you can write it off as a tax deduction.

Basically what it does is mount SSH shares as a local volume, and you can deal with any file just like it was on your own machine, so not only can you edit text-based files with Sublime, you can open images in Photoshop, or do whatever else you want to do, seamlessly. It also plays nice with virtual machines (I use [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/)). It has a daemon that runs as a little icon in the menu bar, so you can open shares whenever you want. You can set favorites and bookmarks, avoiding the need to navigate through subdirectories. It deals with just about any protocol seamlessly - SSH, FTP, SFTP, FTPS, telnet, whatever.

---

In case you're wondering, no, I don't work for Panic (the company that makes Transmit and some other nifty programs), and this isn't advertising spam, I just really love Transmit :)