# Developing directly on the server with Sublime

Tags: sftp, sublimetext

I'm aware of Sublime SFTP, but so far only managed to work with local folder that synced with the remote folder. I wonder if there is a way to work directly on the server, without having to download the files to the local machine, like PHPdesigner does.

Answer (score 0):

seems like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958056/how-to-use-sublime-over-ssh) already supplied several alternatives to that issue.

I personally use sshfs over osxfuse, which is a generic solution allowing me to treat the remote server filesystem as local.

Comment: Hi Tal, I'm not sure this is what I was looking for. As I mentioned, I want to work directly on the server, without having to sync the files to a local folder. My OS is Windows 8.1, don't have Mac or Linux.

Comment: Hey Yuval, SSHFS has a Windows version as well and the equivalent to osxfuse is win-sshfs. I googled it a bit and found Windows instructions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

Answer (score -1):

As much as I hate to use absolutes, you should NEVER develop into a server.  Always work locally (search local development environments with VirtualBox, AMPPS, etc) and then deploy to the server.  Even testing servers.

Reasons:

- working outside of version control is irresponsible and dangerous
- data integrity is compromised with DBs shared across environments
- efficiency
- SECURITY ( buggy development code can expose vulnerabilities) not to mention using unencrypted FTP exposes credentials, etc

Simply put: if you develop directly into a server with FTP or SFTP or whatever, you are doing it wrong