# Shared folder between Windows host and Ubuntu guest, long filenames

Tags: node.js, virtualbox

I'm setting up an Ubuntu guest under Windows using VirtualBox for a colleague to provide him with a Linux-based development environment for a node.js application.

This colleague of mine can't or doesn't want to SSH into the VM and work in emacs or vim; he's a Sublime Text guy. So I have set up the project tree in a VirtualBox shared folder so he can access it from Windows (to edit) and the Linux VM (to build/test).

Unfortunately, `npm install` fails with file system errors. The problem seems to be extremely long path names resulting from deeply nested `node_modules` dependencies. I'm guessing we're hitting a Windows limit on filename length. The `npm install` works just fine in a regular (non-shared) directory in the VM.

Does anyone have ideas about how to deal with this problem? One idea I had was to somehow alias or link `$MY_PROJECT/node_modules` to another, non-shared location, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Update: I'm going to try this hack: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11976.

Update 2: Ended up using samba, which is probably what I should have done in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use one of the multiple ways for sublime to edit remote files over ssh, covered in some detail here

[How to use Sublime over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958056/how-to-use-sublime-over-ssh)

Another is try using the native windows version of node and have your colleague develop locally directly under windows.