# Using RSUB on a machine through SSH with limited permissions

Tags: ssh, permissions, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to use rsub and Sublime 3 to edit files on a remote machine following the instructions posted in the top response of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458814/how-to-open-remote-files-in-sublime-text-3) stack overflow post. However, the machine I am using I do not have permissions to edit anything but my home directory. So I cannot install rsub anywhere but in my home directory and I cannot edit the Path. Presently I get the following error message when trying to open a file with it:

```
rsub: command not found
```

Is there a way to run the commands without these permissions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. Rather than installing it in the directory the tutorial recommended that I did not have access to, I installed it in a bin directory I created in my home directory and changed the permissions in that directory.