# sublime text couldn't make change to remote server files

Tags: sublimetext3

I followed the accepted answer in this link [How to open remote files in sublime text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458814/how-to-open-remote-files-in-sublime-text-3) to edit files on remote server (GCP) using local (MacOS) sublime-text. It worked fine and when I tried to save my modifications to the remote files locally it didn't throw any error. However, I found the files on remote server were not really changed. Did anyone know what is happening here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you just need to add 'sudo' in front of 'rsub -f somefile' and then the save works!