# Is there a way to refresh files opened with rmate (sublime) after a broken pipe?

Tags: ssh, sublimetext3

I am using rmate (sublime) to edit files on a remote server.
After a broken pipe, after I reconnect, I have to close and re-open the files to continue editing and saving the changes.

Similarly, if I rename a file on the remote server, I have to close the file with the old name and reopen the file with the new name.

Is there a way to refresh the files so that I don't need to close and open them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458814/how-to-open-remote-files-in-sublime-text-3) to setup a new rmate/rsub host.

I've recently switched to the [`RemoteSubl`](https://github.com/randy3k/RemoteSubl) package that is mentioned in the accepted answer.

Even tho the last commit comes from *Oct 2019*, the script is still working as expected, with the following improvements compaired to `rsub`;

- support multiple files via rmate foo bar.
- use the same view when opening the same file twice.
- notify when connection lost.
- **resume previous connection when it was lost.**
- better status bar messages when saving file and when encountering errors.
- bring up Sublime Text on different platforms.

<sub>**Note:** I'm not associated with the one of the mentioned packages</sub>

Comment: This is the solution - thank you.

Comment: If another post has an answer to the question being asked, you should flag this post as a duplicate, not reference the other post in an answer with zero added value.