# Sublime Test notify when connection to remote server is lost when using rsub

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I followed [How to open remote files in sublime text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458814/how-to-open-remote-files-in-sublime-text-3) to setup Sublime text to connect to the remote server using rsub.

With recent Sublime build 4126, when the connection to remote host is lost I don't see a message box saying the connection is lost as it used to show earlier.

Is there any setting to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured that i had to install RemoteSubl package along with rsub.
If you are not getting “Connection lost” pop up, it is because of the setting – Sublime Text -> preferences -> Package Settings -> RemoteSubl -> Settings
{
/*
listen host

```
    WARNING: it's NOT recommended to change this option,
    use SSH tunneling instead.
*/
"host": "localhost",

/*
    listen port
*/
"port": 52698,

/*
    display a dialog when connection is lost
*/
"pop_up_when_connection_lost": true,

/*
    color scheme to use for remote windows

    examples:
    - null (use the default color scheme)
    - "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme"
*/
"color_scheme": null
```

}

**pop_up_when_connection_lost** must be set to **true**.