# Best way to work with code on cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, sublimetext3, nodemon

I've lately started with Amazon Web Services and deployed a couple of express applications on EC2 and I find it extremely tedious to edit code on the fly via SSH (ssh is little unresponsive for coding purposes and I'm not really comfortable with nano and vim for heavy editing).

I know I can edit it on my machine and `scp` it to EC2. I was thinking whether there's any way I can setup something like nodemon but for cloud, i.e. whenever I make a change on my local development, it deploys it on cloud with scp? Kind of extending nodemon to cloud.

Or is there any other way to work with that?

Comment: Which code editor do you like to use? Are you on Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I use sublimetext on mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plug-ins and utilities that can allow you to **edit locally with Sublime Text** (a good Australian editor -- please register if you use it a lot!) and have the file **automatically updated** on a remote server.

See:

- Stackoverflow: [How to use Sublime over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15965854/174777)
- [Editing files remotely via SSH on SublimeText 3](https://wrgms.com/editing-files-remotely-via-ssh-on-sublimetext-3/)

There are probably many similar utilities if you go looking for them.