# Creating Eclipse workspace over SSHFS

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, sshfs

I have a Windows machine. On it there is SSHFS Manager (v 0.0.1.5) mounting on F: a shared directory. I would like to place my Eclipse workspace there. But Eclipse fails!

When I give `F:\workspace` path in the workspace selection dialog Eclipse shows error stating "*Workspace at 'F:/workspace' in use or cannot be created, choose a different one.*"

Yet on the F: (and thus the remote directory) it did create an empty `workspace\.metadata\.lock` file (and nothing more). Also I have no issues in reading or writing from F: using Windows Explorer or Notepad++ (for example). This includes editing the `.lock` file itself.

How to make it work?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh :)

Comment: RSA tutorials and documentation suggests using a shared directory (or similar) in first place over other methods. So I tried it and failed.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your eclipse.ini to add this line

-Dosgi.locking=none

This works for me with a Windows host, Ubuntu 14.04 guest, and Winsshfs 0.0.1.5.

Comment: In the mean time I switched to different IDE and gave up on SSHFS (instead I found Samba shares). It would be difficult for me know to verify that approach. But if someone else will confirm it helped let me know and I will accept the answer.