# IDE with remote build feature that is compatible with MIT Kerberos

Tags: c, netbeans, fortran, remote-debugging, kerberos

I'm using cluster resources from my academic provider (**[PDC, Sweden](http://www.pdc.kth.se/)**) that uses the **[MIT-Kerberos authentication protocol](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/)** for the users to sign in securely.

I'm also using **[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html)** to develop C and Fortran code. Netbeans has a feature that lets you build your code on a remote host while you are working on your localhost/Desktop machine. Naturally, this feature requires you to log into your remotehost.

Since Netbeans is using its own SSH client, I cannot connect to the above mentioned remotehost even if I have a valid Kerberos ticket. I have googled this issue, but couldn't find anything related to it.

Has anybody else had a similar issue?
Does anybody know of an IDE for C/Fortran that has a *build on remotehost* feature and is capable of using the Kerberos protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse with the [Photran plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/) are commonly mentioned. I never used it myself, but Eclipse should also [support authentication via Kerberos](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=26939797).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh) for more on Eclipse and SSH.