# Connect remote hadoop server using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, centos, openssh

I am trying to run some map-reduce programs on a remote server of Hadoop 2.0.0, which is running on CentOS 6.4 using ssh.

I am using Eclipse LUNA on my windows 8 machine.

Is there a way to run the programs directly on my Eclipse without converting them to JAR files?

Answer (score 1):

If hadoop is running on a linux machine, you can not connect directly from windows. The connection has to be SSH.

I hope you are looking for something like this:

https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fgettingstarted%2Fgusing.html

The correct answer (similar) to this is here:
[Work on a remote project with Eclipse via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh?rq=1)