# Is there a IDE to develop/build AOSP remotely through SSH?

Tags: ide, android-source, remote-server

Specifically to Android Open Source Project (AOSP), does someone know a good IDE to develop remotely? My scenario is as follow:

1. I have an OSX terminal at which I'm working and typing my code;
2. I have a remote Ubuntu terminal at which my AOSP source, as well as compilation library and needed hardware, are located;

This scenario is much like as cited in **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh)** question. They mention to use Remote System Explorer (RSE) Eclipse's set of plugins to work with. I've tried this, but it not fitted my scenario very well, as AOSP have some build files (i.e. .mk files) to manage that Eclipse seems to get confused with them.

**What I need is: a fast way to develop, build and compile AOSP, in a remote way through SSH connection.**

Any indication should bee very appreciated...

Comment: You should be able to run an X server on your Mac and use your choice of Linux gui editor/IDE by exporting a DISPLAY environment variable pointing at that through the ssh tunnel.   For simply building though, consider just doing that from your bash (or shell of choice) session.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I've made an operational development environment by searching a little more. I've used both suggestion from **[here](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com.br/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh)**. At current moment, I still have some issues with synchronization and automatic builds, but the scenario has become much more faster to develop.