# Build and debug a project on a remote server via SSH with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ssh, remote-debugging

Unfortunately, I do not find a solution for my problem in [this similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh).

I have a server with special hardware and a special (GNU-compatible) toolchain. I can only access this server via SSH.

Now I try to set up a development system with Eclipse. Is it possible to set-up a configuration to be able to build and debug via SSH as if the program would run on my local computer? And if yes, could you tell me a little bit about it? ;-)

Comment: Can you access the server's files through SFTP?

Comment: The files should not be the problem. The main problem is, whether I can use a toolchain which lives on a remote server and is accessible only per SSH as if it would live on my local computer.

Comment: Do you want to run eclipse on the remote server, displaying on your local display? Or do you want to run eclipse on your local computer, accessing things on the other server?

Comment: I would like to access everything on the server. Toolchain and debugger probably via SSH, files via a remote file system (which already works in the case of SSHFTP).

Answer (score 0):

Provided your server is a Linux machine running a X server, you may want to look around SSH -X.

- Install Eclipse on your server
- Install an X11 environment on your client (e.g. for Windows: XMing)
- Connect to SSH with the -X option (e.g. for Windows, there is a checkbox on Putty)
- Launch Eclipse from the ssh connection.