# Develop raspberry pi app with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I just got a Raspberry Pi and I want to develop a java application for it using eclipse. I found the performance of the pi very poor so I don't want to install eclipse on it and use it for developing the app, I would like to use my mac. I thought about different solutions: Use my mac and push the code to github and then pull it on the Raspberry and compile it. Also use the same raspbian image with parallel desktop and after finishing the work deploy the solution on the pi (But actually I want to try the app on the raspberry frequently when I am developing it). Do you have an idea how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **Remote System Explorer** Plugin (installable via eclipse market place).

This Plugin basically adds a remote file system to the eclipse view.
You can create projects on the remote device und use them from eclipse.
Build setup is probably a bit more advanced (have not tried this yet), but should be possible as well.

You can find a step-by-step guide for creating a project in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216878/2448440)

Answer (score 0):

Try this eclipse plugin - http://tsvetan-stoyanov.github.io/launchpi/. It allows you to run/debug java applications remotely.