# Remote control Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm using Eclipse on many different PC's also on nonPrivat PC's like in the university, I would like to run **Eclipse** on an **Ubuntu Server** (I already got one running at home) and access it remotely from another operating system (Windows/Mac/Linux).

I know there are ways like **Xrdp**, but I don't really want to install a **GUI** on the Ubuntu Server to do that. (If it's at all possible to access it over the internet)

Are there other ways to deal with that problem? Maybe something quite different than that?

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions.
You can use `ssh -X user@your.server`. This will create a tunnel for the X protocol, allowing you to run Eclipse with display on your machine, i.e. just

```
mymachine $ ssh -X me@that.server
thatserver# eclipse
```

and you will see the GUI on the local machine, provided you have an X server, which should be standard and is easy to find for a Mac (it is called Quartz).

If you are not willing, or not able, to install X on your machine, you could also install `tightvnc` on the remote machine and a VNC client on your computer. VNC is a different remoting protocol, and can be better than X in some cases, because it has a reputation for fewer round trips in its communication, giving less latency problem.

If you have a database to reach for your project, that can be seen only from the remote machine, maybe inside a DMZ, you might still reach it, creating an SSH tunnel, like this

```
ssh -X -L <database port>:<database server address>:<port number here> me@that.server
```

This way you will be able to access the database with which you talk on port `database port` at address `database server address`, as seen from the remote server `that.server`. The port will be forwarded to `localhost:por number here`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have graphic access to eclipse or do you just need to be able to build projects? If you just want to build projects there is a headless CDT which let's you do that from the command line.

Comment: You may check this answer from another thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/4216878/7743540